# Open ID endpoint for Hotmail/Windows Live

Tags: openid, windows-live-id

Is there one?

I can find articles that talk about it's implementation from 2008:

- http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1745.entry
- http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/microsoft_windows_live_openid.php

But I can't seem to find any actual documentation on how to use it. Anyone used it? Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good Question!

Unfortunately MS **stopped investing into OpenID** for now and there are no plans to be found when they will reopen their efforts for the MS Live ID to become an OpenID.

Official word is in this [Microsoft Privacy and Safety Group Blog Post from August 2009](http://blogs.technet.com/b/privacyimperative/archive/2009/08/28/windows-live-id-openid-status-update.aspx).

"Best" tidbits:

> ...we are in the process of closing the OpenID CTP endpoints...
>
> ...we do not have a schedule that I can publicly share for when we will release full Production support of OpenID for Windows Live ID users...

Comment: I don't think they'll go back to supporting it, especially that Windows Live Delegated Authentication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287637.aspx)!

Answer (score 1):

Its available, these days the info is available at [One Drive Auth](http://onedrive.github.io/auth/readme.htm)

Note: OpenID is changing between different vendors, for example Googles' OpenId expires tomorrow: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration#shutdown-timetable